# Multiple Visual Studio's connecting to one Mac for Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

Our team currently has two business licences to Xamarin and one Mac book Pro, which is connected to the companies network.

If one of us opens the Hello World app within Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7, we can connect, build, deploy to the Mac and see the iPhone simulator running the application.
However, if the second user attempts to do the same, they're unable to connect to the Build Host, as it's currently being used.

Is there a way to either manually disconnect the connection between PC 1 and Mac, so that PC 2 can connect, or can multiple PC's connect simultaneously with a additional build arguments?

Many Thanks

Dom

Comment: I *think* that in order to comply with Apple's licensing, Xamarin limits the Build Servers so they are 1:1 with Visual Studio clients.  I may be wrong about that.

Comment: Thanks @Jason. What you mentioned is true. I've received this from Xamarin Support:"As per Apple's licensing restrictions, you need one Mac per developer, so 2 developers cannot build simultaneously on one Mac, these restrictions are reinforced by Visual Studio.
That being said, you should easily be able to connect one at a time to the Mac build server."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Xamarin 3.3](http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_3/xamarin.vs_3.3/) (stable) for Visual Studio now has a button for quick disconnect from a build host.

[image: visual studio disconnect button]

**EDIT:**

[Xamarin 4.0](http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.0/)

[image: Visual studio disconnect button]

Answer (score 0):

You can run one Mac virtual machine per Visual Studio instance using [VMware Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/features.html) on your Mac. I'm not sure of the legal implications, however.

Answer (score 0):

To disconnect you can just go to the MAC and **unpair** in the "Xamarin.iOS Build Host" (same place you got the password required for pairing.

Then to connect from the second PC you can go (in VS) to:

Tools->Options->Xamarin-> iOS Settings-> Find Mac Build Host... follow the same steps as you did to connect the first PC.